# как построить новый отрезок?

Tags: геометрия

У меня есть отрезок с координатами с тремя координатами точек начала и конца.

И есть длина от начала к новой точке, которая должна лежать на отрезке и длина от новой точки до конца.
Как узнать ее координаты?
Грубо говоря разделить вектор на два.

Comment: Три координаты .. вы имеете ввиду X Y Z ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не совсем понял задачу

Есть координаты начала `p1(x1, y1, z1)` и конца `p2(x2, y2, z2)` отрезка, а также известно расстояние `L` от начала отрезка до точки `p0`?, которая лежит на отрезка.

И надо найти ее координаты.

Если это так, то сделать можно следующим образом:

1. найти длину отрезка:

   ```
    L1 = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2 - z1)^2)
   ```
2. найти координаты точки на отрезке как отношение длин отрезков

   ```
    x0 = x1 + (x2 - x1) * L / L1
    y0 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * L / L1
    z0 = z1 + (z2 - z1) * L / L1
   ```

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли
В второй формуле вконце ошибка и вместо y должна быть z?

Comment: виноват, исправил